# add and delete events from iCalendar?

Tags: python, applescript, icalendar

I'm working on a small python program that automatically schedules events to my iCalendar.

I've got most of it finished, and am at a place where I have all the information I need about an event, I just don't know how to interface with iCal.

I've tagged applescript, because if it is easier to schedule an event via that, I have no problem using it. I would just need to know how to pass information from my python script to the applescript.

Just to clarify I have a Title, Start and End Times, and the Date of an event. I don't think I need anything else, right?

Answer (score 0):

Opening AppleScript Editor and looking at the library for iCal isn't a bad idea.

Here's an example:

```
tell application "iCal"
   tell calendar "My Calendar"
      set theDate to current date
      make new event at end with properties {description:"Event Description", 
         summary:"Event Name", location:"Event Location", start date:theDate, 
         allday event:true}
   end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Alright, so that leaves me with 2 questions. 1) Is it better to be using python or applescript? I potentially have a lot of events to schedule, is there any reason applescript would be slower? 2) How can i send data from my python script to the applescript?

Comment: @user974703: Please ask these questions as **questions** not comments.  "Better" doesn't matter, so don't waste time asking.  "slower" is something you can trivially measure.  "sending data" is part of the Mac OS Python library.  You should (1) read the library and then (2) ask **specific** questions based on code you wrote that doesn't work.